# How can i design tcp messages listener in my Android client?

Tags: android, multithreading, tcp

i'm a newbie for Android.
I'm working on a client(android)-server(java) arcitecture application for my project. I have questions..
My 4-5 activities will send tcp messages to server and get response to do something to their own. So i need a background listener for these messages and then do something in these 4-5 activities. Where can i implement this listener thread to response my different actitivies. Is  it a good way to write 5 AsyncTask in subclass of these Activites to messaging Server?
I think 1 thread can do the work; but how can i bind the activites..
Is it the service that im talking about? But i dont want to do something when my app destroys.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a very similar application and use a singleton to do the work.  When your activity is created, call Listener.getInstance() to get the instance of the Listener.  If it has not been created, create it.

In the Listener object, create a thread to do all the socket communication.  When a message becomes available, post it back to the main GUI thread using a handler (or some other synchronization mechanism).

```
public class Listener implements Runnable, Callback
{
    String ipAddress;
    int ipPort;
    private listener = null;
    Handler handler;

    public Listener
    {
        handler = new Handler(this);
    }

    public Listener getInstance()
    {
        if (listener == null)
            listener = new Listener()
        return listener;
    }

    public void connect()
    {
        thread = new thread();
        thread.run(this);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, ipPort));

        //do your thread/socket work...

        //when a message is available via the socket, post the message back to the main GUI thread using a handler.
        Message msg = new Message();
        //fill the msg with data
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    @Override public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        //hand message to current activity
    }
}
```

A great socket example can be found here:http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

As an alternative, you could do all this work in a service.  I just chose this path when I started.  It has worked well for me.

Comment: thank you for answering, i'm started to write a service to do all this work.